# How to force css cache in production with Symfony2 when its content changes

Tags: php, css, symfony, caching

In production, when minifying the css (php app/console assetic:dump), the file is re-created but the name don't change.

Thus users browser keep in cache the old version. A workaround is to add after the css name a parameter like ?v=12 to force that cache, but is there another solution? How Symfony generate the css filename? Name that file with its md5 would solve the problem, because when the file change its name would also change.

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite,?yui_css'
        'bundles/app/css/style.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

In my source the filename is still the same event after a change in the css :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/b3ba425.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems there is no better way to force user's cache to refresh than adding version number. However this might be automated in nice way:

There is [KachkaevAssetsVersionBundle](https://github.com/kachkaev/KachkaevAssetsVersionBundle) which provides `assets_version:increment` task, so having this bundle all you need to do is:

Add in your **config.yml**

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_version: %assets_version%
```

Then in your **parameters.yml.dist / parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    assets_version: v1
```

The task `assets_version:increment` will increment `v1` value for you.

I would also recommend to add this command to your `composer`'s `post install` or `post update` scripts